# Java HTTP Proxy thought Socket connection

Tags: java, proxy

I would like to to make a http request though a socket connection.

Here's how I am forming my proxy.

```
SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);
socket = new Socket(proxy);
```

If I change the proxy type to socks and point it to a socks proxy, then it works. So I am not too sure why it's not working when I set the type to `http` and point it to an `http` proxy server.

The error I receive lies within the Socket.class and the error is Invalid Proxy.

Comment: have you checked this ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Comment: Yes.  It doesn't really help.  Please don't point me to docs.

Comment: From what I can find, it soulds like the Socket.class doesn't allow http.  only direct and socks

Answer (score 0):

The socket.class didn't allow http.  Socks worked.